# drupal website adding tabs together instead of seperated

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, e-commerce, drupal-theming

Im quite new to drupal and currently I have been trying to develop a new ecommerce theme using/costomizing a existing free commerce theme for learning purposes. So i have come acroos a requirement which i need help from the forum.

the requirement is this!!

the current theme has tabs as shown in the picture 01

picture 01

[image]

but what want is to get all that circled tabs together as shown in the second pic, where items can be viewed by clicking each tab

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: any drupal experts!!!

Comment: is there anybody fluent in drupal

Comment: is this 1 single view? I think it's a HTML issue a missing class or id that will connect those tabs together. Probably missconfiguration

Answer (score 0):

Install and use Drupal Quick tab module. For more information about module see
Drupal Quick Tabs

http://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs